# R: Merge data.table and fill in NAs

Tags: r, merge, data.table

Suppose 3 data tables:

```
dt1<-data.table(Type=c("a","b"),x=1:2)
dt2<-data.table(Type=c("a","b"),y=3:4)
dt3<-data.table(Type=c("c","d"),z=3:4)
```

I want to merge them into 1 data table, so I do this:

```
dt4<-merge(dt1,dt2,by="Type") # No error, produces what I want
dt5<-merge(dt4,dt3,by="Type") # Produces empty data.table (0 rows) of 4 cols: Type,x,y,z
```

Is there a way to make dt5 like this instead?:

```
> dt5
   Type x y z
1:    a 1 3 NA
2:    b 2 4 NA
3:    c NA NA 3
4:    d NA NA 4
```

Comment: Look at the help entry for `merge`. There's an argument called `all`.

Comment: +1 for short self-contained reproducible example, with desired result and what you tried to do. This is a great example of how to right a question and I am surprised it has not got more upvotes.

Comment: @SimonO101, I gave it a +1 for the same reason. I'm surprised that there's actually a down-vote there.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I had not noticed that. That's disappoitning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you explore the `all` argument to `merge`, I'll also offer you an alternative that might want to consider:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "Type", all = TRUE), list(dt1, dt2, dt3))
#    Type  x  y  z
# 1:    a  1  3 NA
# 2:    b  2  4 NA
# 3:    c NA NA  3
# 4:    d NA NA  4
```

Comment: Interesting. Am I right to say that it is faster too as it says in the help "The current implementation is non-recursive to ensure stability and scalability."?

Comment: `Reduce` on a `data.table`? Is that a `data.table`y way of doing things?

Comment: Although I have a badge for [tag:data.table], I admit to not at all knowing "the way". :-(

Comment: Ha. I want a badge!. Have a +1 yourself (though I remain unconvinced by the utility of using `Reduce` here - seriously I am genuinely asking the question so if someone can enlighten me I would like to know).

Answer (score 8):

If you know in advance the unique values you have in your `Type` column you can use `J` and then join tables the `data.table` way. You should set the key for each table so `data.table` knows what to join on, like this...

```
#  setkeys
setkey( dt1 , Type )
setkey( dt2 , Type )
setkey( dt3 , Type )


#  Join
dt1[ dt2[ dt3[ J( letters[1:4] ) , ] ] ]
#   Type  x  y  z
#1:    a  1  3 NA
#2:    b  2  4 NA
#3:    c NA NA  3
#4:    d NA NA  4
```

This shows off `data.table`'s compound queries (i.e. `dt1[dt2[dt3[...]]]` ) which are wicked!

If you don't know in advance the unique values for the key column you can make a list of your tables and use `lapply` to quickly run through them getting the unique values to make your `J` expression...

```
#  A simple way to get the unique values to make 'J',
#  assuming they are in the first column.
ll <- list( dt1 , dt2 , dt3 )
vals <- unique( unlist( lapply( ll , `[` , 1 ) ) )
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Then use it like before, i.e. `dt1[ dt2[ dt3[ J( vals ) , ] ] ]`.